# Generate random data with lat-long

Tags: python, math, random, latitude-longitude

I am trying to generate random data with range of specific latitude and longitude. The code below executes with no errors and also generates output but not fully what I am expecting.

Program:

```
import random
import sys
import math

latitude = 19.99
longitude = 73.78
output_file = 'filename'

def generate_random_data():
    with open(output_file, 'w') as output:
        hex1 = '%012X' % random.randint(0,100)
        flt = float(random.randint(0,100))
        latitude = math.acos(random.random() * 2 - 1)
        longitude = random.random() * math.pi * 2

        output.write('%s %.1f %.6f %.6f \n' % (hex1.lower(), flt, longitude, latitude))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    generate_random_data()
```

The above code runs but gives only one row (which could be indentation problem) But this does not give me random `lat` & `long` in required Geo location as mentioned above.

Output generated:

`000000000020 95.0 3.929691 1.749931`

Output Expected:
`000000000020 95.0 19.999691 73.799931`

And this generates only `one` row where as I am trying to have `million` rows

Comment: The random generation looks right - the thing that might be contributing to the problem is the fact that "output_file" is never defined (and the function is never called).

Comment: Are you sure this works?  I don't recall random.random() taking any  arguments. https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html  What do you want random.random(0,100) to output?  Random ints from 0 to 100?

Comment: @Scott The program is edited as it did show error for the point you raised.

Comment: Running this code creates a file 'filename' with the following data: 000000000025 58.0 4.484670 1.712346.  Is this expected output?

Comment: @Scott `col[0]` and `col[1]` are correct but `col[2]` and `col[3]` are `4.484670` and `1.712346` are wrong I am trying to generate in a given range of `lat` and `long` of `19.99` and `73.78` respectively and also I am getting only one row. I did change the indentations of the `output.write`

Comment: It could help if in your post you create some expected output (range of lat, lon, how many rows, etc.).

Comment: @Scott Done !! Thank you for pointing .. The lat n long range is given in program.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77844/discussion-between-scott-and-sitz-blogz).

Comment: Why not use a specialized package to generate fake data, so you can focus on other more important parts. I would recommend using [Faker](http://www.joke2k.net/faker/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do.  I understand you are writing to a file; I took that off here just for the sake of this example.

```
import random
import sys
import math

latitude = 19.99
longitude = 73.78

def generate_random_data(lat, lon, num_rows):
    for _ in xrange(num_rows):
        hex1 = '%012x' % random.randrange(16**12) # 12 char random string
        flt = float(random.randint(0,100))
        dec_lat = random.random()/100
        dec_lon = random.random()/100
        print '%s %.1f %.6f %.6f \n' % (hex1.lower(), flt, lon+dec_lon, lat+dec_lat)

generate_random_data(latitude, longitude, 5)
```

Prints:

```
31d831302b7f 99.0 73.789561 19.997404 
c6ef41c70ebb 0.0 73.780732 19.994279 
4bc2df5388e3 77.0 73.785531 19.994191 
e7648f673475 40.0 73.786610 19.993679 
a11502c744a6 32.0 73.784650 19.997702
```

**EDIT**: So your function including writing to file would then be the following

```
import random
import sys
import math

latitude = 19.99
longitude = 73.78
file_n = 'random_lat_lon.txt'

def generate_random_data(lat, lon, num_rows, file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'w') as output:
        for _ in xrange(num_rows):
            hex1 = '%012x' % random.randrange(16**12)                
            flt = float(random.randint(0,100))
            dec_lat = random.random()/100
            dec_lon = random.random()/100
            output.write('%s %.1f %.6f %.6f \n' % (hex1.lower(), flt, lon+dec_lon, lat+dec_lat))

generate_random_data(latitude, longitude, 5, file_n)
```

Which generates the data posted above the EDIT into a file named 'random_lat_lon.txt'.

Comment: @SitzBlogz One last thing: If your intention is that `hex1` is a unique identifier you won't quite get that with `'%012X' % random.randint(0,100)
`.  If you want 12 character random strings do this instead: `'%012x' % random.randrange(16**12)`.  In fact I'll update my answer to include that.

Comment: can we have time series also randomly generated? Like start time `HH:MM:SS` and end time `HH:MM:SS` ? I mean to say in two new columns.

Comment: I started writing something but then searched and found http://stackoverflow.com/a/553320/4663466.  So you could do something like `s = '07:00:00'
e = '16:45:00'
f = '%H:%M:%S'` and `strTimeProp(s, e, f, random.random())`.  Which for example could give you `12:39:14`.  If you have any trouble integrating this into the function above post it as a new question and I'll try to answer before someone else :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to call your fonction somewhere.

Generally, in Python you do something like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  generate_random_data()
```

Comment: Output_file is not defined error after this function called

Comment: So..define it. `output_file = "toto.txt"` Plus the random() functiontakes no argument.

Comment: Thanks .. initial issue solved program is edited pls check once

Answer (score 1):

I modified @Scott's response to create a CSV instead of a txt file:

```
import random
import sys
import math

latitude = 0.794501
longitude = -0.752568
file_n = 'random_lat_lon.csv'

def generate_random_data(lat, lon, num_rows, file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'w') as output:
        for _ in xrange(num_rows):
            hex1 = '%012x' % random.randrange(16**12)                
            flt = float(random.randint(0,100))
            dec_lat = random.random()/100
            dec_lon = random.random()/100
            output.write('%s,%.1f,%.6f,%.6f \n' % (hex1.lower(), flt, lon+dec_lon, lat+dec_lat))

generate_random_data(latitude, longitude, 600, file_n)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of this using NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

def random_lat_lon(n=1, lat_min=-90., lat_max=90., lon_min=-180., lon_max=180.):
    """
    this code produces an array with pairs lat, lon
    """
    lat = np.random.uniform(lat_min, lat_max, n)
    lon = np.random.uniform(lon_min, lon_max, n)

    return np.array(tuple(zip(lat, lon)))
```