# python function to generate a timestamp in a range of timestamps

Tags: python

What is the most efficient or most readable or shortest way to generate a timestamp in a range on timestamps. Basically a function that will return a timestamp.

Lets say timestamp has to be later than `1999-04-01T07:00:00Z` and earlier than `2016-06-03T15:18:07Z` in this exact format.

This timestamp will be then used as a url param to GET some entities created either earlier or later than this. Also, is this some certain standard of a format? Does it have name?

Comment: Instantiate `datetime` objects, subtract them to get a `timedelta`, generate a random number between `0` and the seconds in the `timedelta`, add `timedelta(seconds=my_random_number)` to your smaller timestamp.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate a random date between two other dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553303/generate-a-random-date-between-two-other-dates)

Answer (score 1):

> as a url param to GET some entities

It seems that you need a *string* of a certain format.

> is this some certain standard of a format? Does it have name?

Take a look at [ISO_8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). You can use `.isoformat()` from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) to get exactly that.

> Lets say timestamp has to be later than `1999-04-01T07:00:00Z` and earlier than `2016-06-03T15:18:07Z` in this exact format.

Shortest and most efficient way would be to simply return `"1999-04-01T07:00:01Z"`, for example. Technically, that does the job.

However, I suppose you need something more, like returning a random new one each time or incrementing date with some step or whatnot.

**EDIT**: question about generating random timestamps in a given range was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553303/generate-a-random-date-between-two-other-dates)

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the ISO_8601 reference. Still, I wanted to see what the best way to generate random values in this range. I will the use this in a performance test for an API that gets documents from solr based on when documents were created.