# Generate Random Timestamp in a given range?

Tags: python, random, time

I'm trying to do something like:

```
start=input("select starting date, format example : Jan 01 00:00:00")
end=input("select ending date")

if start>end:
     start,end=end,start

print(randomize_time(start,end))
```

Output:

```
>>> Aug 05 13:15:59
```

I have tried using random.randint, but if I select a range like:
00:00:00 && 01:00:00, the only part that is randomized is the hour, minutes and seconds will be ignored (since I'm doing random.randint(0,0)).

How would I do that properly?

Thanks in advance SO!

Comment: You can convert the input to timestamp, and generate a random time between start and end, and then convert back to datetime

Comment: can you paste the method body for randomize_time? You can pass the epoch time as parameters and them get a random timestamp and convert it back to a date string.

Comment: The epoch thing rights perfectly. Thanks ;à

Answer (score 4):

You can use something as below:

```
from random import randrange
import time

start_timestamp = time.mktime(time.strptime('Jun 1 2010  01:33:00', '%b %d %Y %I:%M:%S'))
end_timestamp = time.mktime(time.strptime('Jun 1 2017  12:33:00', '%b %d %Y %I:%M:%S'))

def randomize_time(start_timestamp,end_timestamp):
    return time.strftime('%b %d %Y %I:%M:%S', time.localtime(randrange(start_timestamp,end_timestamp)))
```

Comment: I converted the time in epoch and used randrange to generate a value between start and end time. converted it bask as per format

Comment: Add description to the answer instead of in a comment!