# Generate random date in a particular month and year

Tags: python, python-datetime

I have a list of dates. For each of these dates, keeping the month and year same, I need to generate a random date. I tried using this code:

```
def get_random_date(date):
    r_int = random.randint(1, 28)  #line 2
    rand_date = date[0:4] + date[5:7] + str(r_int)
    randm_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(rand_date, '%Y%m%d').date()
    return randm_date
```

But in this code I would never be getting 29, 30 or 31. If I remove the 28 in line 2 I might get 30 Feb or something like that. How to avoid this?

Edit: I do not need to get a random date b/w 2 dates. This is a different question. Plz let me know what other details I can provide to not get this marked duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate a random date between two other dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553303/generate-a-random-date-between-two-other-dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, use `calendar` lib:

```
import calendar, random

def randomdate(year, month):
    dates = calendar.Calendar().itermonthdates(year, month)
    return random.choice([date for date in dates if date.month == month])
```

This function will return a `datetime.date` object.

**In detail (TL;DR):**
`dates` is a iterator of all the dates in the weeks of that month. It includes several days from previous and next month. For example, `list(calendar.Calendar().itermonthdates(2017, 8))` will also include 2017-07-31, 2017-09-01, 2017-09-02, 2017-09-03. So I used list comprehension to filter them out.

---

There is only one short hand: It cannot deal with dates between 1582-10-04 and 1582-10-15. [Ten dates were skipped to make calendar correct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1582). This is due to the python `datetime` lib.

Comment: This totally works the way I wanted it to. And, I don't think the short hand will be a problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import timedelta
from random import randrange
import calendar

def rnd_date(date):
    mrange = calendar.monthrange(date.year,date.month)
    d2 = date.replace(day=mrange[1])
    d1 = date.replace(day=mrange[0])
    delta = d2 - d1 
    result_int = delta.total_seconds()
    rnd = randrange(result_int)
    return d1 + timedelta(seconds=rnd)
```

Examples:

```
date = datetime.strptime('2/28/2020 1:30 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')

rnd_date(date)
datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 10, 20, 37, 14)

day=0
rndate=None
while day != 29:
    rndate = rnd_date(date)
    day = rndate.day
day
29

rndate
datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 29, 9, 4, 41)
```

Comment: I understand that this would help in getting a random date b/w 2 dates. I need to get a random date in the same month of the date that is passed in the function.

Comment: I am getting this Error - 
ValueError: day is out of range for month

Comment: Did you send a date to function, like my example? what date that generated the error?