# Generate Random Date/Time Python 2.6

Tags: python-2.6

I want to create a function that will create a random timestamp and cast into a string. Tried a couple ways but not sure if the problem is using python 2.6

Tried this but running into error that says:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'datetime.timedelta' and 'float'
```

```
def gen_datetime(min_year=2018, max_year=datetime.now().year):

    start = datetime(min_year, 1, 1, 00, 00, 00)

    years = max_year - min_year + 1

    end = start + timedelta(days=365 * years)

    return start + (end - start) * random.random()

...
randomTime = str(gen_datetime())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multiplication of a `datetime.timedelta` object with a `float` was only introduced int Python 3.x. You can confirm this comparing the [Datetime docs from Python 2.x](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) and the [Datetime docs from Python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Notice that Python 2.x accepts `int` and `long` so it should be fine multiplying it by:

```
random.randint(a,b)
```

which will generate an `int` between **a** and **b**

Comment: That works, however its not giving a random ***time*** along with the date. Any idea why that is happening? And it is not entirely randomizing the date.

Im trying this:

`return start + (end - start) * random.randint(3,5)
`

Comment: The way you did, you are only changing the years of your datetime, not the time. My guess is that you should change your `timedelta(days=365 * years)` and modify the seconds, such as `timedelta(seconds=rondom_seconds)`. [Take a look in nosklo's response here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/553448/11522398).