# FIlter Data Frame by time

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a large data frame that is being imported through an excel sheet. I already filtered it to exclude weekends but also need to do the same so only daytime hours eg 7:00 - 18:00 will be displayed. Here is what the data frame looks like after successfully taking out weekends.

[picture of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjWH4.png)

```py
isBusinessDay = BDay().is_on_offset
 
match_series = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp(America/New_York)']).map(isBusinessDay)
df_new = df[match_series]

df_new
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to use filters on your datetime field using the `Series dt accessor`.

In this case...

```
filt = (df['timestamp(America/New_York)'].dt.hour >= 7) & (df['timestamp(America/New_York)'].dt.hour <= 18)

df_filtered = df.loc[filt, :]
```

More reading: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html

For more and a sample of this in action, see the below code block. The random date generator was [taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553303/generate-a-random-date-between-two-other-dates) and modified slightly.

```
import random
import time
import pandas as pd

def str_time_prop(start, end, time_format, prop):
    """Get a time at a proportion of a range of two formatted times.

    start and end should be strings specifying times formatted in the
    given format (strftime-style), giving an interval [start, end].
    prop specifies how a proportion of the interval to be taken after
    start.  The returned time will be in the specified format.
    """

    stime = time.mktime(time.strptime(start, time_format))
    etime = time.mktime(time.strptime(end, time_format))

    ptime = stime + prop * (etime - stime)

    return time.strftime(time_format, time.localtime(ptime))


def random_date(start, end, prop):
    return str_time_prop(start, end, '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p', prop)

dates = {'dtfield':[random_date("2007-1-1 1:30 PM", "2009-1-1 4:50 AM", random.random()) for n in range(1000)]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=dates)

df['dtfield'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dtfield'])

filt = (df['dtfield'].dt.hour >= 7) & (df['dtfield'].dt.hour <= 18)

df_filtered = df.loc[filt, :]

df_filtered
```