# How to generate a random expiry date for a credit card?

Tags: python, random, generator

I'm trying to make a program that generates random credit card details.
I don't know how to generate a random expiry date for the card and the expiry date should be `expiry>current year`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553303/generate-a-random-date-between-two-other-dates)

Comment: Can you show some code and give us some more pieces of information.

Comment: @nikpau kind of  because a cc lasts 3 to 4 years. So it should kind of be like a date between 2022 and 2027 and it should give output like this. Example: `06/26`. It shouldn't give date only print month and year. IDK if this makes sense sorry

Comment: @Sailesh語 Just define the `random_date()` function as `def random_date(start, end, prop): return str_time_prop(start, end, '%m/%y', prop)` and then call it with for example `print(random_date("1/08", "8/22", random.random()))`